# more org-preview-latex-fragment issues on mac

Tags: org-mode, latex

I must have messed up my .spacemacs file, latex preview in org mode is no longer working.    My config is below.   It seems to be a path problem.  The output when I attempt to preview is:

```
../../../../../private/var/folders/dn/mnflj2l13kx84fzxzfhv81v80000gq/T/orgtexXCZV8h.dvi: No such file or directory
This is dvipng 1.17 Copyright 2002-2015, 2019 Jan-Ake Larsson
```

The ../../../../..
seems to be the problem.  The whole path to the .dvi file is correct from my home directory (ie. the dvi file exists there) but not from the directory where the .org file is located.

Suggestions?

```
 '(org-preview-latex-process-alist
       (quote
       ((dvipng :programs
         ("lualatex" "dvipng")
         :description "dvi > png" :message "you need to install the programs: latex and dvipng." :image-input-type "dvi" :image-output-type "png" :image-size-adjust
         (10.0 . 10.0)
         :latex-compiler
         ("lualatex -output-format dvi -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f")
         :image-converter
         ("dvipng -fg %F -bg %B -D %D -T tight -o %O %f"))
        (dvisvgm :programs
          ("latex" "dvisvgm")
          :description "dvi > svg" :message "you need to install the programs: latex and dvisvgm." :use-xcolor t :image-input-type "xdv" :image-output-type "svg" :image-size-adjust
          (1.7 . 1.5)
          :latex-compiler
          ("xelatex -no-pdf -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f")
          :image-converter
          ("dvisvgm %f -n -b min -c %S -o %O"))
 (imagemagick :programs
              ("latex" "convert")
              :description "pdf > png" :message "you need to install the programs: latex and imagemagick." :use-xcolor t :image-input-type "pdf" :image-output-type "png" :image-size-adjust
              (1.0 . 1.0)
              :latex-compiler
              ("xelatex -no-pdf -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f")
              :image-converter
              ("convert -density %D -trim -antialias %f -quality 100 %O")))))

  ;(setq org-preview-latex-default-process 'dvisvgm) 
  (setq org-preview-latex-default-process 'dvipng)
```

Comment: Is your home directory really five levels down from `/`? Generally (at least on Linux, but also in most Unixes I know), it's just two levels: `/home/<username>`.  The `dvipng` section seems pretty vanilla: have you made any changes to it? What version of Org mode are you running?

Comment: From my home directory:  ls ../../../../../private works (I don't know why!! bc as you said it is only two levels down), but the ls command doesn't work from the location of the org file.

Comment: org mode is 9.6.6

Comment: It's because when you get to `/`, its parent is `/' as well. But I don't understand why you get such a bizarre path. How is that related to the directory of the Org mode file? Normally, you get the path of the current directory and so the image file is under that directory, not five levels up and over - but is it "over" in another part of the tree or are they close and it's just the path that Org mode produces that is bizarre?

Comment: The .org file is located at /Users/home/Dropbox/EmacsVault/Org , I am not sure why it is happening.  I just tried texfrag and it worked fine.